# Fetch JSON object from Google WebApp from another Google WebApp

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have two Google Spreadsheets, each of which with some Apps Script attached. Eventually I want to deploy both as WebApps so they can communicate with one another through their public URLs. For now, I have only deployed one of them so I can test this functionality.

We'll call Script A the one that's deployed as a WebApp and Script B the one that is trying to send a request to Script A's URL. The goal here is for Script A to return a JSON object to Script B.

In Script A, I have this code:

```
function doGet(request) {
  var data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]; //dummy JSON object

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

In Script B, I have this code:

```
function pullJSON(URL) {  
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {"contentType": "application/json"});
Logger.log(data);
}
```

When I access Script A's exec URL, I get a JSON object. However, when I run *pullJSON()* in Script B (feeding it the same URL), the Logger shows a long HTML file filled with metadata (there's no visible content when I view it in my browser). I'm confused as to why this is the case...I know there are a couple of redirects to return JSON, but it is my understanding that the *UrlFetchApp.fetch()* method defaults to following all redirects.

Could this be an OAuth issue? Script A is published to run as User Accessing the App, though I also tried running it as me.

Thoughts?

Comment: I just saw that I suggested such a workflow in one of your recent post...is this attempt related to that suggestion ?  If so then the answer below is actually valid for both posts. You will notice that the webapp is running as me so if it sends an email it will be on my account of course... the recipient can easily be specified as a third parameter by adding &recipient=example@test.com.

Comment: How did you ever solve this? If you're still looking, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130847/get-json-from-a-google-apps-script-web-app-from-another-web-app-without-anonymou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a script as a webapp to run as a service you can only use the .exec url to call it with urlFetch because the development url (the one ending with .dev) is only accessible by you and the request does not come from you but from Google.

I deployed your example and tested it with your code as follows :

```
function pullJSON(URL) {  
  var URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzqRgv1XfUUrAimvD31OXx89GdhjeBd45SBODaq1c7bkGVusio/exec"
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {"contentType": "application/json"});
Logger.log(data);
}
```

The result is as expected :

[image]

You can test it yourself since the app is deployed as "run as me" and accessible to anyone even anonymous.

If you want to restrict its access you'll have to add some parameters to the URL and handle these parameters in your server webapp to check the origin of the request.

Parameters are simply added to the url like this :

```
 var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL+"?user=serge&secret=secretcode", {"contentType": "application/json"});
```

then in your server script check it like this :

```
var user = request.parameter.user;
var secret = request.parameter.secret;
```

and you'll get the user and secret.

---

**EDIT :** here is a complete example of both scripts with a security control :

webapp :

```
function doGet(e) {
  var data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]; //dummy JSON object
  if(e.parameter.user=='serge'&&e.parameter.secret=='secretcode'){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }else{
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('You are not allowed to get this result, user should be '+e.parameter.user+' and code should be '+e.parameter.secret)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
}
```

and test script :

```
function pullJSONSecure() {  
  var URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyzoFbcjTXMCALTOlscwAZP6gY1mWc1mkbWb84LYO-qeQk16xw/exec"
 var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL+"?user=serge&secret=secretcode", {"contentType": "application/json"});
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

If you try this script and change the user name or the password you will see what happens.

---

**EDIT 2 :** deployment parameters :

[image]

Comment: Can you paste for me the exact code for your WebApp? (https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzqRgv1XfUUrAimvD31OXx89GdhjeBd45SBODaq1c7bkGVusio/exec)

Comment: When I access your webapp with the URL above from Script B, it works. When I access my own, it does not.

Comment: the code is exactly as it is above in the second example. The first is the same without condition, it goes like this (copy/paste of yours): `function doGet(request) {
  var data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]; //dummy JSON object
Logger.log(request);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data)+request)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}`

Comment: if your code isn't working it's probably a matter of deployment and/or version. double check the parameters and the version published. see also edit2 please.

Comment: Yep, ok, those settings are definitely the issue. I'm deploying within an Enterprise copy of Drive, so the "anyone, even anonymous" feature is disabled for security reasons.

Comment: Ah, that's a no way ... as explained above, the request comes from Google server. A simple solution is to use a private gmail account for the webapp, outside of your domain.  Also : how about accepting the answer ? :-)

Comment: That won't be possible due to security concerns, so I will have to go with another solution. Thanks for your help, though!