# Get JSON from a Google Apps Script web-app from another web-app without anonymous access

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, permissions

First, this question is a duplicate of [Fetch JSON object from Google WebApp from another Google WebApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331087/fetch-json-object-from-google-webapp-from-another-google-webapp;) however, that question is 6 years old, and the answer does not work in my situation -- details below.

--

I have a Google Apps Script web-app that returns JSON and is published such that it runs as me and **anyone in my organization** can access it. For various reasons, I cannot publish it as anonymous as [answered from the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331087/fetch-json-object-from-google-webapp-from-another-google-webapp).

```
function doGet(request)
{
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(request)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I am trying to call this web-app from another web-app using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(...)` but it seems to return a bunch of HTML instead of the expected JSON output.

```
function testIt()
{
    var a = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/a/verizon.com/macros/s/[redacted]/exec");
    Logger.log(a.getContentText());
}
```

I understand that the second web-app, the one with `testIt` runs from Google's servers so the `UrlFetchApp.fetch` call is anonymous.

There must be a way to pass the authentication token of the user running `testIt`?

I tried this, but it did not work either:

```
var a = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/a/verizon.com/macros/s/AKfycbxseotobMLXnid5PT_UpBRWZdNrhhX2EOegeCd4b9gFA2VbAvLm/exec", {
    "method":"GET",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or is what I am after not possible?

Basically, I have a web-app I own and someone else has a web-app they own. I am trying to find a way they can call my web-app from their web-app to do certain things that their web-app does not have access to (writing some data to some sheets and sending some emails from my account).

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, in your script, when `Basic` is modified to `Bearer`, what result will you get? And also, can you confirm that the scopes of Drive API are included in your scopes? If that is not included, please put `// DriveApp.getFiles()` as the comment line. By this, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is included. I think that in the case of Web Apps, this can be used for accessing. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#accesstokenforaccessingtowebapps)

Comment: *Basically, I have a web-app I own and someone else has a web-app they own* As long as both are in the same domain and webapp1 has read access to the webapp2,  the above workaround mentioned by Tanaike should work.

Comment: Can you confirm that the comments above solved your issue?

Comment: Yeah, that is working. I am such an idiot. Thank you @Tanaike! If you put that as an answer then I'll mark it so.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I post it as an answer. I thought that this will be also useful for other users. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes, this will be useful to others I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it accesses to the Web Apps using the access token, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
"Authorization" : "Basic " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
```

#### To

```
"Authorization" : "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
```

- As an important point of this case, please confirm whether the scopes of Drive API are included in your scopes.
- If that is not included, please put `// DriveApp.getFiles()` as the comment line. By this, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is included in the scopes. I think that in the case of Web Apps, this can be used for accessing.

#### Reference:

- [Access token for accessing to Web Apps](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#accesstokenforaccessingtowebapps)