# How to authenticate programmatically when running an Apps Script Web App from another Apps Script project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am new to Apps Script and trying to understand the basics of running/triggering a script in one account using another. With just caveat: I'd like to run the script with the user accessing the script instead of the user owning the script -- in order to assign the run time to the user accessing.

I am however running into the following issues.

---

Starting with a test SpreadSheet with Sharing set to Anyone With Link can edit and the following code in the script project page:

```
function doPost(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1tWV6ELJEGkWkSXvdf9kQemvH-tDVTx0od4JHht2ZBeU');
  var tab = sheet.getSheetByName('ref');
  tab.getRange(1,1).setValue(new Date());
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(0)
}

function doGet(e){
  return doPost(e)
}
```

and having published the project as a Web App with execution set to user accessing and access enabled for Anyone. Entering the following link in the browser manually fills cell A1 with current time and the page displaying '0', as intended,

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwNhYg1BRKi38pNf_z0peGuYt6gsqvauCvo-eiGgCYJJk4QDpjm/exec
```

**IF** I enter the link while still signed in with the account that created the test SpreadSheet.

If I enter the link with a different browser without GSuite log-in, I am required to sign in, which is also as expected. After all, a G Suite account is required to run the script per deployment of the Web App .

However, when I tried triggering the script using a different GSuite account and Apps Script project, I still ran into the sign-in page and also other issues. Out of

```
function test1(){
  const scriptURL='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwNhYg1BRKi38pNf_z0peGuYt6gsqvauCvo-eiGgCYJJk4QDpjm/exec';  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(scriptURL)
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
}

function test2(){
  const scriptURL='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxay75fTBt3doTyMFUPK0-GpK9hMZ4hVkYdiwYUBMhPfEN6hUJH/exec';  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(scriptURL, {
    method:'POST',
    payload:'nothing'
  });  
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
}

function test3() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AKfycbwNhYg1BRKi38pNf_z0peGuYt6gsqvauCvo-eiGgCYJJk4QDpjm');
  Logger.log(sheet.getName());
}

function test4() {
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const scriptURL='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxay75fTBt3doTyMFUPK0-GpK9hMZ4hVkYdiwYUBMhPfEN6hUJH/exec';  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(scriptURL, {
    headers: {Authorization:'Bearer '+ token},
    method:'GET',
    payload:'nothing'
  });  
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

`test1()` produces a long body of text in Log starting with

```
Logging output too large. Truncating output. 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
  <title>Sign in - Google Accounts</title>
  <style>
```

and `test2()` returns an eror

```
Exception: Request failed for https://script.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
    at test2(Code:23:30)
```

Neither test triggered the script in `doPost(e)` since the cell A1 was not updated.

`test1()` seems to encounter the sign-in page. Yet, at the same time, `test1()` is executed via a sign-in G Suite account.

It may also be worth noting that that `test3()` is able to access the Google SpreadSheet file in question. I also tried calling `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` because why not. `test4()` has the same response as `test1()`.

I don't know where to begin diagnosing with the error encountered in `test2()`.

---

How do I get around the sign-in page?

In particular, is there a way to make the script accessible by any other GSuite account with access permission to the Google SpreadSheet in question and executed by user accessing as opposed to user owning the SpreadSheet?

What am I doing wrong with the POST version?

Any help is apprecriated!

Comment: To get around the `test2()` issue you could get more information from the response if you use [muteHttpExceptions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters)

Comment: And, I believe if you read the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64130847/4243927 you will know how to authorize the caller web app at the destination web app. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Aerials: Thank you for responding to my question! I did try adding auth token in the same way in the linked question except with `headers: {Authorization:'Bearer '+ token}` and I got the same responses.

Comment: Try just using the doGet() and not the doPost();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your question, I understood your situation as follows.

- The script of Web Apps is put to the container bound script of the Spreadsheet of `1tWV6ELJEGkWkSXvdf9kQemvH-tDVTx0od4JHht2ZBeU`.
- The Spreadsheet is shared as `Anyone with the link` of `editor`.
- The Web Apps is deployed as `Execute the app as: User accessing the web apps` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`.

This answer supposes my above understanding. So when my understanding is not correct, please tell me.

### Modification points:

- At `UrlFetchApp`, when `payload:'nothing'` is used, it requests as POST method even when `method:'GET'` is used. Please be careful this.
- In your script of Web Apps uses the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`. In this case, at first, it is required to authorize the scope by own browser (each user's browser). When this is not done, even when the script and the access token with the scopes of client side are correct, an error of `Authorization needed` occurs. Please be careful this. It seems that this is the current specification.
- If the whole script (`test1` to `test4`) of your client side is the script in your question, the scopes are `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`.  I think that the scope is not enough for requesting the Web Apps. In this case, for example, please add `// DriveApp.getFiles()` to the script editor. By this, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is automatically added by the script editor and this scope can be used for requesting to Web Apps. Also, you can use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

  - In the case of scopes of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`, an error of `Unauthorized` occurs.

When above points are reflected to your situation, it becomes as follows.

### Usage:

#### 1. Prepare Web Apps side. (server side)

In this case, I think that your settings can be used. Please redeploy the Web Apps as new version just in case. And please confirm the URL of Web Apps again.

#### 2. Prepare client side.

1. Please access to `https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxay75fTBt3doTyMFUPK0-GpK9hMZ4hVkYdiwYUBMhPfEN6hUJH/exec` using own browser (user side.) And please authorize the scopes of Web Apps.
2. I would like to propose to modify `test4()` of your script as follows.

   ```
    function test4() {
      var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      const scriptURL='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxay75fTBt3doTyMFUPK0-GpK9hMZ4hVkYdiwYUBMhPfEN6hUJH/exec';  
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(scriptURL, {
        headers: {Authorization:'Bearer '+ token},
        method: 'GET',
    //    payload:'nothing',
        muteHttpExceptions: true
      });  
      Logger.log(response.getContentText())

      // DriveApp.getFiles()  // This is used for adding a scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly. This is used for requesting to Web Apps.
    }
   ```
3. Please run `test4()`. By this, `0` is returned from Web Apps and you can see it at the log.

### References:

- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Comment: Thank you very much for the write-up! I signed in and granted permission manually. In the same browser, I made the modifications and ran `test4()` but got error 401 return in the log: `<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD><BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"><H1>Unauthorized</H1><H2>Error 401</H2></BODY></HTML>`. Any idea what I can do next?

Comment: @Argyll Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, now when I tested `test4` of my answer above flow again, no error occurs and `0` is returned. And I can confirm that the script works again. So I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide your whole script and the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Argyll By the way, there is an important point. It's the scope for requesting to Web Apps. When the scope of the client side is not enough, an error of `Unauthorized` occurs as I have already mentioned in my answer. So please be careful this. About this, can you confirm whether `// DriveApp.getFiles()` of the comment line, which is for adding the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`, is included in the script of the client side, again?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't understand what `// DriveApp.getFiles()` was supposed to do. I added the line and that prompted a second authorization. Afterwards, the functions run as intended. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Argyll Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. As other method for setting the scopes, there is the method for editing the manifest file (`appsscript.json`). But, in that case, when new methods for using other scopes are used in the script, an error occurs because the scopes are fixed by the manifest file. So when the script is developing, in my answer, I recommended to use the automatically detection of the scopes by the script editor.